# height of div is not 100%

Tags: css, html

I want to make a webpage with `<div>` and 100% height. I keep having problems with the height. I now have a height of 100% + 100px;

I create a header div which is 100px height. That is the only static height I use. Below that div I made another div which should fill the page. But when I set this to 100% it will add 100% to the 100px. When I set this to auto it will be only +- 150px height. This is the HTML

```
<!-- header -->
<div id="header">
     <div id="logo"></div>
     <div id="menuTop">menutop</div>
</div>
<!-- center -->
    <div id="linkerbalk">
        <div id="login">login naam</div>
        <div id="menuLinks">Menu<br />Menu<br />Menu<br />Menu<br />Menu<br /></div>
    </div>
<!-- footer -->
```

and the CSS i use is this:

```
html,body {
    height:100%
}
body {
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
#header {
    width:auto;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FC3;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#logo {
    background:url(../img/logo.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#27c9cb;
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menuTop {
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:#2d2e33;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:auto;
}
#linkerbalk {
    background-color:#2d2e33;
    height:100%;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    overflow:auto;
}
#login {
    background-color:#2faaaf;
    height:35px;
    width:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#menuLinks {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one of the ways to achieve this:

I have wrapped your HTML with a container div and given it 100% - height of header i.e. 100px.

```
.container{
    height:calc(100% - 100px)
}
```

[**Working fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LpcYF/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a wrapper.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div class='top'>
        </div>

        <div class='mid'>
        </div>

        <div class='bot'>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body,
#wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}
.top {
    height: 20%;
}
.mid {
    height: 70%;
}
.bot {
    height: 10%;
}
```